# C# MVC Get value of Display attribute with ResourceType parameter by reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, reflection

I have a "generic" Razor view for displaying table for a model which is a collection like `IEnumerable<IFirstLevetOverviewModel>`. On this view, I'm looping for all items in the collection and displaying columns and header via reflection. So to build header I'm using this code:

Model property:

```
 [Display(Name = "Personalkategorie_OffiziellerStellenplan"]
 public string PersonalNumber { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @foreach (var prop in Model.FirstOrDefault().GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                if (!prop.PropertyType.Name.Contains("IEnumerable"))
                {
                    <th style="width: calc(100%/@propsCount);">
                      @DisplayNameReflected(prop);
                    </th>
                }
            }
```

Helper:

```
 @helper DisplayNameReflected(PropertyInfo property)
 {
        if (!property.PropertyType.Name.Contains("IEnumerable"))
        {
            var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
            if (dd != null)
            {
                var name = dd.Name;
            }
        }
}
```

And it works fine. But now I have a requirement to implement localization, so I need to use ResourceType 
(`[Display(Name = "Personalkategorie_OffiziellerStellenplan", ResourceType = typeof(Labels))]`).
But I can't figure out how to improve my helper to get localized name. Is it possible at all? Or maybe there is some cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it can be done through ResourceManage:

```
@helper DisplayNameReflected(PropertyInfo property, ResourceManager resManager)
    {
        if (!property.PropertyType.Name.Contains("IEnumerable"))
        {
            var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
            if (dd != null)
            {
                <p>
                    @resManager.GetString(dd.Name, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                </p>
            }
        }
}
```